# com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

idea develop plugin:

```
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer.entryPoint(RemoteJdbcServer.java:28)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer.main(RemoteJdbcServer.java:16)
```

build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    //....
    //....
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30")
    //....
    //....
}
```

How to solve this bug when testing idea plugin

Comment: Plugins don't use your local app's Gradle files. 

You need to edit the classpath in the [`.vmoptions`](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) to include the MySQL driver, or you need to copy the same file into the IDE's installation directory.

Comment: Also refer [Database Connections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-database-connections.html) on how it manages drivers

Answer (score -1):

it means that com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver not found in your properties file or any class file. if you play with around spring framework add the file in the following:

```
application.properties
#MySQL local database
domain.datasource.type=MYSQL
domain.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3600/store;
domain.datasource.driver-class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
domain.datasource.username=store
domain.datasource.password=store
domain.datasource.generate-dll=false
```

vice versa in pure java

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        DbConfig dbConfig = DbConfigParse.getDbConfig();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConfig.getUrl(), dbConfig.getUsername(), dbConfig.getPassword());
        return connection;

    }
```

Comment: The error is from an IDE **plugin**, not a Spring/plain Java app.